# How to remove the numerator to find a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have

$$ 60 = 40/X + X $$

How do I remove $40$ and find $X$?

As I understand it, I have to multiply both sides by $X$. But if I do that then I'm left with

$$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
&60X = 40 + X &\Rightarrow 
\\ 
&60X - X = 40 &\Rightarrow
\\ 
&X - X = 40 / 60 &\Rightarrow
\\ 
& 1 = 2/3 &
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

And I think I ended at the wrong spot...

Comment: Minor slip. When you multiply both sides by $X$, you should end up with $60X=40+X^2$.  You may have forgotten to multiply the $X$ at the right end by $X$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas - Do I have to do that to all other variables in the equation? for instance if that equation was instead `60 = 40 / X + x^2 + X` it would come out to be `60X = 40 + X^3 + x^2`?

Comment: @Aedon, yes -- you do it for each _term_, whether or not they contain variables. It's not a special magical rule, it's just the ordinary $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ applied with $a=x$, $b=\frac{40}{x}$ and $c=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know $X\ne 0$ so you can multiply by it.  That will leave you a quadratic equation for $X$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, how will that leave me with a quadratic equation for X?

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $X$ gives $60X=40+X^2\implies X^2-60X+40=0$.

Comment: Ok I see now, thank for the help :)